# Somar valor dos nodes childrens ao valor dos parents em array recursivamente

Tags: php, array

Boa tarde.

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de array abaixo, como somar os valores dos `node_value` dos nós filhos aos valores `node_value` dos `parents`, recursivamente?

```
Array
    (
    [0] => Array
    (
        [node_id] => 1
        [0] => 1
        [text] => Node A
        [1] => Node A
        [node_value] => 43.5
        [2] => 43.5
        [node_master] => 
        [3] => 
        [children] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
            (
                [node_id] => 2
                [0] => 2
                [text] => Node B
                [1] => Node B
                [node_value] => 12.4
                [2] => 12.4
                [node_master] => 1
                [3] => 1
                [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                    (
                        [node_id] => 5
                        [0] => 5
                        [text] => Node E
                        [1] => Node E
                        [node_value] => 88.9
                        [2] => 88.9
                        [node_master] => 2
                        [3] => 2
                    )
                )
            )
            [1] => Array
            (
                [node_id] => 3
                [0] => 3
                [text] => Node C
                [1] => Node C
                [node_value] => 52.6
                [2] => 52.6
                [node_master] => 1
                [3] => 1
                [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                    (
                        [node_id] => 4
                        [0] => 4
                        [text] => Node D
                        [1] => Node D
                        [node_value] => 7.4
                        [2] => 7.4
                        [node_master] => 3
                        [3] => 3
                    )
                    [1] => Array
                    (
                        [node_id] => 8
                        [0] => 8
                        [text] => Node H
                        [1] => Node H
                        [node_value] => 12.8
                        [2] => 12.8
                        [node_master] => 3
                        [3] => 3
                        [children] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                            (
                                [node_id] => 10
                                [0] => 10
                                [text] => Node J
                                [1] => Node J
                                [node_value] => 90.0
                                [2] => 90.0
                                [node_master] => 8
                                [3] => 8
                                [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [node_id] => 13
                                        [0] => 13
                                        [text] => Node M
                                        [1] => Node M
                                        [node_value] => 18.8
                                        [2] => 18.8
                                        [node_master] => 10
                                        [3] => 10
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                            [1] => Array
                            (
                                [node_id] => 11
                                [0] => 11
                                [text] => Node K
                                [1] => Node K
                                [node_value] => 25.7
                                [2] => 25.7
                                [node_master] => 8
                                [3] => 8
                            )
                            [2] => Array
                            (
                                [node_id] => 15
                                [0] => 15
                                [text] => Node O
                                [1] => Node O
                                [node_value] => 77.0
                                [2] => 77.0
                                [node_master] => 8
                                [3] => 8
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
            [2] => Array
            (
                [node_id] => 6
                [0] => 6
                [text] => Node F
                [1] => Node F
                [node_value] => 32.1
                [2] => 32.1
                [node_master] => 1
                [3] => 1
                [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                    (
                        [node_id] => 7
                        [0] => 7
                        [text] => Node G
                        [1] => Node G
                        [node_value] => 49.7
                        [2] => 49.7
                        [node_master] => 6
                        [3] => 6
                        [children] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                            (
                                [node_id] => 9
                                [0] => 9
                                [text] => Node I
                                [1] => Node I
                                [node_value] => 19.4
                                [2] => 19.4
                                [node_master] => 7
                                [3] => 7
                                [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [node_id] => 14
                                        [0] => 14
                                        [text] => Node N
                                        [1] => Node N
                                        [node_value] => 2.4
                                        [2] => 2.4
                                        [node_master] => 9
                                        [3] => 9
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                    [1] => Array
                    (
                        [node_id] => 12
                        [0] => 12
                        [text] => Node L
                        [1] => Node L
                        [node_value] => 49.7
                        [2] => 49.7
                        [node_master] => 6
                        [3] => 6
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Estou tentando chegar a uma função PHP para varrer o array e somar os valores...

Answer (score 0):

Para que a soma funcione num array tão vasto e aninhado terá que ser recursiva, assim como já indicou na pergunta. O pormenor é que tem de ser feito do fim para o inicio, logo a parte que soma tem que vir obrigatoriamente após a recursão.

Exemplo de implementação desta lógica:

```
function somaRecursiva(&$arr){

    if (isset($arr["children"])){ 
        //se este nó tem children, a soma tem de ser calculada e por isso começamos com 0
        $arr["node_value"] = 0;

        foreach ($arr["children"] as $key => $value){ //para cada filho no array children
            //somar o resultado desse filho ao value corrente
            $arr["node_value"] += somaRecursiva($arr["children"][$key]);
        }
    }

    return $arr["node_value"] ?? 0; //retornar a soma para cima
}
```

[Exemplo no ideone](https://ideone.com/TIsvpq)